# the subscription is not authorized for this feature

Tags: azure, azure-vm-role

I just create new Azure account with bizspak. I added certificate and i wanted upload VM role, but they said "the subscription is not authorized for this feature" why?

My script

```
csupload Add-VMImage -Connection "SubscriptionId=e6db325e-***********b42462b967fb;CertificateThumbprint=7989E0348C37F*************4D0629F" -Description "VMRole" -LiteralPath "D:\MEDFAR Inc\VMRole\VigilanceForAzure.vhd" -Name VigilanceForAzure.vhd -Location "North Central US"
```

have you any idea why?

Thanks you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Azure portal, click on the Home link and then select "Beta Programs".  Most likely you aren't approved for the VM Role.  Click the "Apply for Access" next to VM Role and once approved, you will be able to use this Beta feature.

Comment: Do you know how long time for apply this feature?

Comment: It should take a week or less.

Comment: Took just over 24 hours when I did this last week.